# oracle.ManageddataAccess throws ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword while inserting data

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle-manageddataaccess

I am connecting to a remote Oracle DB and using `Oracle.ManageddataAccess.dll` to perform update and insert. I am able to update data to it but while I'm trying to insert it throws `ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword` exception but I'm just trying to insert into it.

```
string cmdQuery = string.Format(@"insert into HKSTF087.FUELCHARGES ( [QTM_ID] ,[TITLECODE] ,[FUELCHARGERATE] ,[ISSPECIALRATE] ,[EFFECTIVEFROMDATE] ,[EFFECTIVETHRUDATE] ,[CREATEDBY] ,[CREATEDDATE] ,[UPDATEDBY] ,[UPDATEDDATE]) values ({0}, '{1}', {2}, {3}, TO_DATE('{4:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), '{5}', '{6}', TO_DATE('{7:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), {8}, {9})", mtcRate.QTM_ID, mtcRate.TITLECODE, newDefaultFuelRate, 0, providedEffectiveFromDate, "2099-12-31 00:00:00.0000000", "system", DateTime.Now, "null", "null");
```

and it would look like

```
insert into HKSTF087.FUELCHARGES ( [QTM_ID] ,[TITLECODE] ,[FUELCHARGERATE] ,[ISSPECIALRATE] ,[EFFECTIVEFROMDATE] ,[EFFECTIVETHRUDATE] ,[CREATEDBY] ,[CREATEDDATE] ,[UPDATEDBY] ,[UPDATEDDATE]) values (19874, 'AARC', 19.1, 0, TO_DATE('08/15/2017 00:00:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), '2099-12-31 00:00:00.0000000', 'system', TO_DATE('08/30/2017 17:25:05', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), null, null)
```

and when hits `ExecuteNonQuery()` it throws the `ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword` exception.

here's the query using which I am able to insert the Oracle DB from a Link service using SQL server

```
INSERT INTO MTCT..HKSTF087.FUELCHARGES
       ([QTM_ID]
       ,[TITLECODE]
       ,[FUELCHARGERATE]
       ,[ISSPECIALRATE]
       ,[EFFECTIVEFROMDATE]
       ,[EFFECTIVETHRUDATE]
       ,[CREATEDBY]
       ,[CREATEDDATE]
       ,[UPDATEDBY]
       ,[UPDATEDDATE])
 VALUES
       (4446
       ,'ABCD'
       ,12
       ,0
       ,getdate()
       ,'2099-12-31 00:00:00.0000000'
       ,'system'
       ,getdate()
       ,null
       ,null)
```

Comment: what's getdate()?

Comment: Oracle uses quotation marks `"..."` for quotations, where MS SQL uses brackes `[...]`. `insert into "HKSTF087.FUELCHARGES" ( "QTM_ID" ,...`

Comment: @user7294900 GETDATE() is a built in function in SQL SERVER. I'm connected to the oracle DB via a link server in sql server. But in C# I'm directly using the Oracle DB

Answer (score 0):

> and it would look like
>
> ```
> insert into HKSTF087.FUELCHARGES
> ```

is different than your full example.

> ```
> insert INTO MTCT..HKSTF087.FUELCHARGES
> ```

Also `getdate()` is not a known function on oracle but this might not be a problem when using linked server. I am not sure about that

And as also mentioned in comments oracle needs "" instead of []

`[QTM_ID] ,[TITLECODE]` should be `"QTM_ID" ,"TITLECODE"`

Comment: I'm connected to the Oracle DB using a Link Server facility available in SQL Server. and getdate() is a build in function in sql server to get the current date

Comment: I updated my answer about that since I was not sure about that part

Comment: Appreciate the correction unfortunately that didn't solved the problem.

Comment: are you able to catch the exact query in the profiler ? Maybe that would give some hint to the problem